# Getting "fieldof" function when decompiling NET code with dnspy

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, ilspy, dnspy

I compiled some .NET in dnspy, and having some trouble with this statement

`fieldof(<PrivateImplementationDetails>{D87A3940-7D04-49D9-B7B7-2971825FAF29}.$$method0x6000519-1)`

I do understand this isn't part of c#, and is actually something from MSIL. I've seen some other posts that talk about this but the thing that I can't seem to get right is these values `{D87A3940-7D04-49D9-B7B7-2971825FAF29}.$$method0x6000519-1`. Would these values be referring to something specific in my context? If yes, then how do I find these values, in order to convert this to proper c# code.

Comment: *convert this to proper c# code* why you think that it is possible? Maybe it was written in c++/cli

Comment: It was written in c#. I have rest of the decompiled code with me.

Comment: Just because it was possible to show (part of) the IL code to C# does not mean that it was originally written in C#.

Comment: Also dnspy(Dec 7, 2020) is old and knows nothing about newest c# versions

Comment: Looks like the backing field of a private property setter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61026604/17034

Answer (score 1):

There are things that can be expressed in IL - including things that the compiler can emit indirectly via C# and the many compiler rewrite steps (async/await, expression trees, iterator blocks, lambdas/delegates, local function captures, anonymous types, etc) - that cannot be expressed directly in regular C#.

`fieldof` describing is one of these IL instructions. It is an imaginary C# keyword that describes certain metadata token load operations. You can't write that natively, just like you can't natively name a type `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{D87A3940-7D04-49D9-B7B7-2971825FAF29}` - perfectly valid in IL, but not in C#. You'll have to use reflection via `GetField()` in your version. The `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{D87A3940-7D04-49D9-B7B7-2971825FAF29}` etc here is the compiler-generated rewrite of whatever that was originally - which involves generating an entire new type to implement the simple-looking language syntax. My guess would be "async" or "lambda", but I'd need more code to say for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the generous reply but I was able to circumvent this issue by completely abandoning the method that was invoking this, since I found out it didn't have much to do with what I was trying doing.